# Writing scope to complex multiple associations - Rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am having challenges writing a scope that displays `live_socials` created by users belonging to a `category_managementgroup` called `client_group`.

```
Social.rb
belongs_to :user
scope :live_socials, -> {where(['date >= ?', Date.current])}

CategoryManagementgroup.rb
has_many :users

User.rb
has_many :socials
belongs_to :category_managementgroup
```

the below scope displays all the socials for users in the category_managementgroup called client_group:

```
users.joins(:socials, :category_managementgroup).client_group.flat_map(&:socials)
```

> i am unsure how to extend the scope to display the `live_socials`
>   (socials that have not expired). i tried the below but no success:

```
users.joins(:socials, :category_managementgroup).client_group.flat_map(&:socials).live_socials
```

> i get the below error:

```
2.3.0 :264 > ap users.joins(:socials, :category_managementgroup).client_group.flat_map(&:socials).live_socials
  User Load (0.5ms)  SELECT "users".* FROM "users" INNER JOIN "socials" ON "socials"."user_id" = "users"."id" INNER JOIN "category_managementgroups" ON "category_managementgroups"."id" = "users"."category_managementgroup_id" WHERE "category_managementgroups"."name" = 'Client Group'
  Social Load (0.1ms)  SELECT "socials".* FROM "socials" WHERE "socials"."user_id" = ?  [["user_id", 10]]
NoMethodError: undefined method `live_socials' for #<Array:0x007ff2f9834570>
```

Comment: Try applying `live_socials` before `flat_map` and add below scope to User
`scope :live_socials, -> { joins(:socials).where(['socials.date >= ?', Date.current])}`

Comment: thank you soo much! Can you make your comment an answer to the question so i give it a mark as your suggestion worked perfectly

Comment: Added as an answer @ARTLoe

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try applying `live_socials` scope before `flat_map` and add below scope to User model

```
scope :live_socials, -> { joins(:socials).where(['socials.date >= ?', Date.current])}
```